# Is it possible to measure time performance of the functions that are called inside jar of some library?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am using some library in my maven based project. The jar of this library may/may not contain some other dependent libraries.

I am calling *xyz* function of this library. There is a requirement where I need to check time taken by each of the functions that are called inside *xyz* function. These functions may/ may not be publicly accessible.

Any idea how to do this ? Would `aspect` work in such scenario ?

Comment: The answer is **yes**, but in order to tell you how to do this, you need to do your homework first by providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. So please edit it. Thank you. Here on SO we talk about code rather than about abstract, coding-related questions. Otherwise you will attract speculative answers and debate them in comments rather than solving your problem quickly, see the first answer by _Yuvaraj G_ and your reaction to it below.

Comment: @kriegaex I will provide the details as per the guidelines mentioned by you. Need some time but will post it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, aspects should work. Here is the small example for spring package

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository *)")
public void springBeanPointcut() {
}


@Around("springBeanPointcut()")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Enter: {}.{}()",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
    try {
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Exit: {}.{}()",
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                    joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        }
        return result;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.error("Error:{}.{}()",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

        throw e;
    }
}
```

Configure your logger format for logging millisecond time log, or just put your logic to compute the time taken.

Comment: Are you sure this is working ? I tried this with many functions of internal library (spring and other libraries) but it is not getting caught by Aspect. Those functions are definitely being executed as I cross-checked it by adding debug point inside the functions. Also, no logs are being generated by AspectJ Compiler (for internal functions) during weaving process, the same is getting generated for functions that I have defined.

Comment: Facing same issue with weaving at load time (using aspectj compiler) as well. My own classes getting weaved at load time but the not the ones in the library. May be it is NOT possible to do it, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917509/6629469